# Hyperlinks and runtime error 13 in vb6 application

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am working in an vb6 application that uses multiple Excel files.

The problem appears in this line:

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("C12"), Address:=MainForm.txt_report, TextToDisplay:="See Report"
```

When I run the program it works ok up to this line. Here I get a "Runtime Error 13, Type Mismach". I press the debug button, then I do nothing, and after that I press the "continue execution" button, and all works ok. The links are added to the worksheet correctly.

I really don't know what is happening. It seems like vb needs to wait a moment before execute that line. I try using a `MsgBox()` before that line and the error dissapears. However, if I use `wait` or `sleep` fuctions instead, the problem still there.

I have searched in google but didn't find nothing useful.

[EDIT:]
I think this code is causing the problem:

This makes the error to happen:

```
DoEvents
For i = 1 To cant_filas
        col = oDataBaseSheet.Range(WS.Cells(i, 1)).Column

        With temporal_sheet
            .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(last_row, col)).Copy
        End With

        oTemplateSheet.Range(WS.Cells(i, 2).Value).PasteSpecial
Next
```

This solve the problem:

```
For i = 1 To cant_filas
        col = oDataBaseSheet.Range(WS.Cells(i, 1)).Column

        With temporal_sheet
            .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(last_row, col)).Copy
        End With

        oTemplateSheet.Range(WS.Cells(i, 2).Value).PasteSpecial
Next
DoEvents
```

Comment: What's happening with the workbook before this operation? Is it being opened, saved, created or switched to?

Comment: The WB was opened before. In this sub I get a sheet from that WB:

`Set oNFSheet = oNewFileWB.Sheets("NF")`

then I use with , end with sentences

Comment: Are you doing something before that line that can't complete until it gets a slice of processor time? Try adding a DoEvents before that line. If that works you need to look at what you are doing leading up to the .Hyperlinks.Add call.

Comment: It works! I have edited my question and put some code that I think is involved in this issue. I think this `for` is causing the problem. If I add the `DoEvents` before, it doesn't work but if I add the sentence after the loop, it works ok. Maybe it happens because of switching sheets inside.
Thanks you @jac !